# How do I determine if the left or right mouse button was clicked in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program in Java that uses both the left and right mouse buttons. The default `MouseMotionListener` and `MouseListener` trigger for both mouse clicks.

Is any way to determine what button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `getButton()`

It returns **1 for leftClick** and **3 for rightClick**.